# use adb to install .apk file on phone, game does not show up, but shows up in delete list

Tags: android

I installed my game onto my phone using adb. It shows up on the delete app screen but not on the regular app screen, I think there is a problem with my phone registering applications correctly.  Help!

Heres the install log from command prompt:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install D:\EclipseWorksp
ace\GreenThumbs\bin\GreenThumbs.apk
1462 KB/s (443800 bytes in 0.296s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/GreenThumbs.apk
Success

Edit:By "delete app screen" I meant when you are on the app screen and you hit menu and then remove, you go to a screen where you can select apps to uninstal.

Here's my manifest, it does have the intent and it was working at one point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.hernblog.GreenThumbs"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

        <application>
           <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        </application>
        <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
               android:targetPackage="com.hernblog.GreenThumbs" android:label="GreenThumbs Tests" />

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
                <activity android:name="GreenThumbs" 
                          android:label="@string/app_name"
                          android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
                    <intent-filter> 
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
                    </intent-filter> 
                </activity> 
        </app`lication>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It shows up on delete app screen"?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: What's the "delete app screen"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct intent in your AndroidManifest.xml. It sound's like you don't have the launcher intent. These few lines should be under your activity block:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ian is right, but you should also make sure that the package signature of you class remains the same from one version to another.

BTW your package name and your activity name looks wrong:
Try something like:

```
package="com.hernblog"
```

and

```
android:name=".GreenThumbs"
```